# ZF3: Как настроить EventManager событие MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER для отработки только в одном Модуле?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework-3

Есть два модуля: **Application** и **Blog**, в каждом из них есть файл **Module.php** со своей логикой.
В этих файлах есть метод `onBootstrap` в нем я запускаю `EventManager` на слушание события `MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER` и ожидаю что модули **Application** и **Blog** не будут пресекается, но на деле обрабатывают оба метода, как это изменить? Хочу что бы в каждый модуль был приватным

Примерный листинг **Module.php**

```
namespace Application;

use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

class Module
{
    /**
     * Listen to the bootstrap event
     *
     * @param MvcEvent $e
     */
    public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        /**
         * настройки EVENT_RENDER
         */
        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, [$this, 'onRender']);
    }

    public function onRender($e)
    {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Решение:** Создаём метод `init()` в нем регистрируем общий `SharedManager` слушателя, вешаем его на `MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH` для текущего `__NAMESPACE__`, после чего повешенный наш метод, будет отрабатываться только для текущего модуля

**Файл: Module.php**

```
<?php 
namespace Application;

use Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ConfigProviderInterface;
use Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManagerInterface;
use Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent;

/**
 */
class Module implements ConfigProviderInterface
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return array_merge(
            require __DIR__ . '/../config/module.config.php',
            require __DIR__ . '/../config/router.config.php'
        );
    }

    public function init(ModuleManagerInterface $manager)
    {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);

        $eventManager = $manager->getEventManager();
        // Register the event listener method.
        $sharedEventManager = $eventManager->getSharedManager();
        $sharedEventManager->attach(__NAMESPACE__, MvcEvent::EVENT_DISPATCH,  
                                          [$this, 'onDispatch'], 100);
    }

    public function onDispatch(MvcEvent $e)
    {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);

        $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER, [$this, 'onRender']);
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER_ERROR, [$this, 'onRenderError']);
        $eventManager->attach(MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH, [$this, 'onFinish']);
    }

    public function onRender($e)
    {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
    }
    public function onRenderError($e)
    {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
    }
    public function onFinish($e)
    {
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
    }
```